# How to detect text in UITextView is empty?

Tags: ios

It is easy for UITextField to check empty text...But I have a custom UITextView.If I have input text like @"     "; We don't know what I input,but only can read the length of the text. How can I detect the empty text like "\n" , "", "      "?Any idea?

Comment: Your actual goal is to know if the text contains only white space?

Comment: If you can't access UITextView's text property I don't think you can manage to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check it:

```
if(![[textField.text stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]] length]) {
   //string is all whitespace or newline

}
```

Answer (score 1):

**For Swift 5.1**

```
    if textView.text.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).isEmpty {
        // TextView is empty (or only has whitespaces and newlines) then ...
        // buttonSend.isEnabled = false
    } else {
        // TextView has some text, then ...
        // buttonSend.isEnabled = true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `- (NSString *)stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:(NSCharacterSet *)set` with the white space character set and check the length of the result string.

Answer (score -1):

You can check through counting characters if there will no character in uitextview then characters count will be 0 and we can check on it's base:

```
if(yourTextView.text.characters.count == 0)
    {
        //if empty then
    }
    else
    {
       //if not empty then
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't recognize whitespaces and new lines